# Unity WebGL Update not called on Active and Enabled game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, browser, unity-webgl

Running into a weird issue on WebGL builds. The issue doesn't happen in the editor.
I have multiple game objects that will stop having their update called after a few seconds loading the game.

I know the objects exist since I can call gameInstance.SendMessage from the browser's console on the object. I added a debug method that prints if the object is active and it is. It has the script's component attached, the component is enabled, the game object on which the component is is active. I can even call SendMessage("MyObject", "Update") and it will call the update method once, printing everything correctly.

The issue happens once in a while. Some times it won't happen for a few hours and then will happen once every other times. The game is not frozen, I still have loading animations running.

It sounds like a race condition, but I can't put the finger on what could be causing Unity to stop calling "Update" on active game objects.
Is anyone aware of a condition or a bug in Unity WebGL where Update would stop being called?
If there's something in an infinite loop, would that also freeze loading animations?

Although I’m not sure since the bug is hard to reproduce, this seems to happen only on webgl builds made on macOS

Currently using Unity 2017.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I've never run across this.

Comment: Do you know of any check I could do, any path I could look into? I’m running out of ideas on what to look for. If there’s an infinite loop, the animations would be frozen right?

Comment: No, I'm at a loss. Sorry.